# Can AER and S2S tunnel connections both work in parallel

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network

Can Azure Express Route and Site-to-Site VPN gateway connection tunnel both configured on azure side and both have active connectivity to on-premises network and if yes, can azure express route act as primary and site2site as backup(secondary) for AER?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is a [common scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-howto-coexist-resource-manager).